# What XPath selects odd TRs from a table, starting with the third?

Tags: dom, xpath, xhtml

I have a table:

```
<table>  
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>  
</table>
```

I need an XPath to select odd rows, starting on the third row (3, 5, 7, 9, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think 'position()' function of XPATH will do the job. Returns the index position of the node that is currently being processed. you need to do position() mod 2.

Here is XSLT solution

```
<xsl:for-each select="tr">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1 and position() > 1">
      ...do smthng ....
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>...do something else...</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:foreach>
```

Answer (score 19):

```
"/table/tr[position() mod 2 = 1 and position() > 1]"
```