# What's the equivalent XPath expression for css selector 'p:nth-of-type(2n)'?

Tags: xpath

Explanation of css selector ':nth-of-type', see http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-selectors-20010126/#selectors

Is it possible to transform css selector 'p:nth-of-type(2n)' to equivalent XPath expression?

Anybody help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's (Python) [cssselect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect) translation:

```
descendant-or-self::*/p[(position() +0) mod 2 = 0 and position() >= 0]
```

Which can be simplified to

```
.//p[position() mod 2 = 0]
```

Through lxml.cssselect:

```
>>> import lxml.cssselect
>>> lxml.cssselect.CSSSelector('p:nth-of-type(2n)').path
u'descendant-or-self::*/p[(position() +0) mod 2 = 0 and position() >= 0]'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution I've found at [What XPath selects odd TRs from a table, starting with the third?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081394/what-xpath-selects-odd-trs-from-a-table-starting-with-the-third)

```
/p[position() mod 2 = 1]
```